# What's Don doing in the woods?

Tags: plot-explanation, deep-water

In *Deep Water* (2022) Melinda loses her scarf during a picnic and Vic goes back on the next day to retrieve it. While he was at the creek he gets surprised by Don, who finds the lost scarf.

But what was Don doing there?

We know that he was talking to Melinda about her suspicions and he had hired a private investigator, but by this point in the movie Vic had already uncovered the PI (and it doesn't seem anyone followed him to the woods).

It's also not implied that Melinda told Don about the picnic or the scarf, although that's possible (but why would she do that?).

Did Don know Vic's whereabouts that day or was he there by coinicidence?

Answer (score 2):

This a question that the film left unanswered.

In an article titled, "Deep Water's Biggest Questions Left Unanswered", one of the questions listed is, "How Did Don End Up at the Gorge in Deep Water?"

> When Vic went to get Melinda's scarf back at the gorge in the finale, Don saw him there ... However, the film never explained why Don would be there. Melinda knew Vic was going for the item, but she didn't contact Don, who magically showed up.

I've also tried to see if the creators gave any sort of explanation in other materials/interviews/etc. and haven't found any.

Comment: Hence the question.

Comment: @Joachim Yes, exactly! The film gave no answer.

Comment: I feel like "it's never explained" is a perfectly valid answer. Granted, it's hard to prove a negative, and easy to come up with some kind of speculative idea, but sometimes, a plot hole is just a plot hole.

Comment: @F1Krazy exactly, I asked because I wasn't sure if I missed something or it was just a plot hole.